# Jquery slide need content to stay open on hover

Tags: jquery

Im having trouble with my jquery slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(".events").hover(function() 
  {
      $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  }, function() {
      $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

When i hover over my image, the hiden content slides out and when im not hovered it slides in, thats great but i need to minipulate it so that the hidden content will stay open when i hover over the content and not just the image.
can anyone help me, im new to web desighn and have been stuck on this for some time.
Thanks in advance.

I spoke too fast, i tryied the solution above and its not working. My slide wont even open and its stoped all the other slides on my page from opening when i only changed one of them not sure what the problem is. this is my html:

info text goes here

–

Hi thebiffboff i copied my html and css to the fiddle link u sent and used the solution you showed me and it worked perfectly but it wont in my own page, how could i go about looking for the problem

Comment: what is the html markup for the hidden content and image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your image and hidden content in a wrapper, then bind your hover event to this wrapper. I have created an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMz6f/1/) for you. I have also added the .stop() method which clears the current animation queue, otherwise if you hovered in and out a number of times quickly, the slide would keep sliding up and down after you'd finished.

Comment: Thank you so much you solved both my problems and i only asked one :-)

Comment: Pleased to help, feel free to vote up the answer/mark as correct :)

Comment: I spoke too fast, i tryied the solution above and its not working. My slide wont even open and its stoped all the other slides on my page from opening when i only changed one of them not sure what the problem is. this is my html:     <div class="events">
  <img src="events.jpg" width="300px" height="249" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="einfo">
info text goes here
    </div>

Comment: Hi thebiffboff i copied my html  and css to the fiddle link u sent and used the solution you showed me and it worked perfectly but it wont in my own page, how could i go about looking for the problem

Comment: You are closing the .events div before the .einfo div, so it is no longer a child of it. Move the closing div tag to after the closing tag for .einfo. And yes this will affect others on the page, they will either need to be updated to match, or give this one new class names and different jquery events.

Comment: i copied all my html and css to fiddle link and used your solution and i works perfectly any idea of why this might not work on my site? I have the slides in a table could this be the problem?

Comment: Can you give a link to your site or create a fiddle with your html, css and javascript for this? If not you could look for errors in firebug or dev tools?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nicky/2RqK4/.... most of the slides work here but not on my own site could the problem be my js plugin??? i cant figger this out

Comment: thanks for all your help your solution is deffenitly right ill keep looking for my mistake